# Android: Making onDraw() efficient in Custom View

Tags: android, bitmap, android-custom-view

I am implementing my own custom view in android. I have divided my view into a grid consisting of more then 500 cells. Each cell is represented by a Rect. Now I am setting a tile as background for each cell. So, for setting the background of whole view I am filling each cell with an image. Over it I have some movable items. So whenever I move an item I have to invalidate() the whole view to update the element's position. So onDraw() is called, which results in again filling each cell of the grid with a bitmap image. I want to avoid this, as I think this is computationally expensive (Drawing bitmap for more then 500 cells). Is there anything like snapshot of canvas or something that can be used to make the view onDraw() efficient.

Here is my onDraw() function

```
@Override
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    super.onDraw(canvas);
    if(!mSizeChanged)
    {
        return;
    }
    // For filling all the cells of the grid. mGraphs.getCells() returns cell list. 
    // Drawing done under this loop is never changed.
    for(CenterRect rect : mGraphs.getCells())
    {
        //Logic for drawing different bitmaps
        if(rect.getRow() < 3)
        {
            canvas.drawBitmap(mud, null, rect.getRect(), null);
        }
        else if(rect.getRow() == 3)
        {
            canvas.drawBitmap(mudGrass, null, rect.getRect(), null);
        }
        else if(rect.getRow() < mMidRow) {
            canvas.drawBitmap(grass, null, rect.getRect(), null);
        }
        else if(rect.getRow() == mMidRow) {

            canvas.drawBitmap(grassWater, null, rect.getRect(), null);
        }
        else {
            canvas.drawBitmap(water, null, rect.getRect(), null);
        }

    }
    //Drawing movable elements
    for(Element element : testElements)
    {
        canvas.drawBitmap(element.getBitmap(mContext), null, element.getRect(), null);
    }
}
```